# Asp.Net on IIS - Add default route to url

Tags: asp.net, iis, routes

I am trying to change the default URL of my Asp.Net website on IIS. At the moment the URL leading to the default index.html, is just http://myservername/. But I would actually prefer to extend the URL to http://myservername/route1, which then still routes to the default html. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Microsoft URL Rewrite Module](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337) and install it

and add this to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/route1" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error now. Probably because the route1 does not lead to anything to the website. How can I fix this?

Comment: In IIS creating an application 'route1' inside the website was the solution. However the rule you gave is perfect to redirect users which route to the websites url.